# How does greasemonkey/tampermonkey run userscripts since eval is not allowed?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I don't understand how is the tampermonkey programmed since it interprets userscripts (written in javascript), but extensions aren't allowed to eval(=run) any scripts (and therefore the userscripts too).
Or is the extension having it's own interpreter of the userscripts?

Comment: You can still inject a `<script>` element into the _DOM_.

Comment: Use the source Luke. https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey

Comment: There is a way to do this using the "tabs" permission and `chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
      code: yourCodeString
   });`
But it seems Tampermonkey is doing it some other way, because their userscripts' paths are coming from the background "userscript.html" page. I haven't figured out how they are doing this, but the method with `chrome.tabs.executeScript` is working too